# Sending the same transaction to contract on Binance Smart Chain

Tags: binance

Hey guys I want to send the same transaction that I sent days before.
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xd8e83d4f5bf2c687cf559ef3533629f419a6fc3fc896ac29304c0395cd95e861

How I can repeat it?

I tried with:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x93baa78c81be4f69f2d954fc57959678f6d368d8dd02933cbdb65ad195c71620

but it failed.. where I am wrong?

Comment: It totally depends on the contract. The transaction provided interact with a contract that doesn't have source code verified so it is not possible to provide a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same call, in the [first tx](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xd8e83d4f5bf2c687cf559ef3533629f419a6fc3fc896ac29304c0395cd95e861) (the successful one) you pass the following input -

```
0x7f8661a1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008f
```

On the [failed tx](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x93baa78c81be4f69f2d954fc57959678f6d368d8dd02933cbdb65ad195c71620), this is the input -

```
0x7f8661a1
```

Which is the signature of `exit(uint256 amount)`, but without the `amount` parameter.

Add the `amount` parameter and it will be the same.

Comment: Fails again - https://bscscan.com/tx/0x007e063c70ac1f41f80971c1df63f7aff522dc067b0abf9c3b5814b9d10dd638
Can you check my all transactions to this contract and see whats going on? There was a website that I used to withdraw my Staked tokens and now the website is gone and I can't withdraw my tokens, so I'm trying to make Exit transaction, but always fails...

Comment: I cracked the code right now, thanks a lot! :P